# Calling C++ method from Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linker-errors

I have the following files.

foo.h (C++ header file) 
foo.mm (C++ file) 
test_viewcontroller.h (objective c header file) 
test_viewcontroller.m (Objective c file)

I have declared a method donothing() in foo.h and defined it in foo.mm.Lets say it is

> double donothing(double a)
>   {
>        return a;
>   }

Now,I try to call this function in test_viewcontroller.m

> double var = donothing(somevar);

I get linker error which says "cannot find symbols" _donothing() in test_viewcontroller.o 
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone please point me as to what is wrong?

---

Let me be precise :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 

extern "C" 
{
      char UTMLetterDesignator(double Lat);
      NSString * LLtoUTM(double Lat,double Long,double UTMNorthing, double UTMEasting);
      double test(double a);
}

#endif
```

@Carl

I have included my code sample.Are saying that I need to wrap only the test() method in ifdef.I dont understand what difference it can make.Can you please explain?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`test_viewcontroller.m` is looking for a non-C++-mangled symbol name for `donothing()`.  Change its extension to `.mm` and you should be good.  Alternately, put an `extern "C"` declaration on your method declaration in `foo.h` when compiling the C++ file.

You want to have it look like this:

foo.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double donothing(double a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

foo.mm:

```
#include "foo.h"

double donothing(double a)
{
    return a;
}
```

test_viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "foo.h"

- (double)myObjectiveCMethod:(double)x
{
    return donothing(x);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding extern "c".but i get a new error - "Expected identifier or '(' before string constant"

Comment: @whocares, you need to add the `extern "C"` only for C++ - that means wrapping it in an `#ifdef __cplusplus` block.

Comment: @Carl - Thanks a lot for the response! Linker error is gone now!! but I got a new warning in "test_viewcontroller.m" - implicit declaration of function "donothing()".I believe that this happens only when I have not included the header file which has function declaration.but I have an imported foo.h in "test_viewcontroller.m".Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @whocares, I'm guessing that means your `#ifdef` block is too big.  Put *just* the `extern "C"` inside the `#ifdef`, not the whole function declaration.

Comment: @Carl - Thanks a lot for the detailed reply! works as advertised :) I have registered in Stackoverflow!!

Comment: @whocares: and now you need to accept the answer, since it fixes your problem.