# Bad Exception after using a C++ class in IOS

Tags: c++, ios

I'm trying to add fuzzy search to an iOS App I have built using an existing C++ implementation of double_metaphone by Maurice Aubrey http://aspell.net/metaphone/. I've renamed his main class double_metaphone.mm, set it to File Type C++ Source and got the project to build.

However I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error after I call the `DoubleMetaphone` method. Most of my App uses ARC and I see a number of memory management things in the double_metaphone.mm class. That said I am most suspicious of how I'm trying to get my answer back from the method. Here is the relevant part of double_metaphone.h (I enclose the method declaration in extern "C" as per [Calling C++ method from Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456239/calling-c-method-from-objective-c)).

```
void
DoubleMetaphone(const char *str,
            char **codes);
```

Here are relavant parts of the method implementation in double_metaphone.mm

```
void
DoubleMetaphone(const char *str, char **codes)
{
int        length;
metastring *original;
metastring *primary;
metastring *secondary;
int        current;
int        last;

current = 0;
/* we need the real length and last prior to padding */
length  = strlen(str); 
last    = length - 1; 
original = NewMetaString(str);
/* Pad original so we can index beyond end */
MetaphAdd(original, "     ");

primary = NewMetaString("");
secondary = NewMetaString("");
primary->free_string_on_destroy = 0;
secondary->free_string_on_destroy = 0;

MakeUpper(original);

/* skip these when at start of word */
if (StringAt(original, 0, 2, "GN", "KN", "PN", "WR", "PS", ""))
current += 1;

/* Initial 'X' is pronounced 'Z' e.g. 'Xavier' */
if (GetAt(original, 0) == 'X')
  {
  MetaphAdd(primary, "S");  /* 'Z' maps to 'S' */
  MetaphAdd(secondary, "S");
  current += 1;
  }

/* main loop */
while ((primary->length < 4) || (secondary->length < 4))  
  {
  if (current >= length)
      break;

  switch (GetAt(original, current))

.....
```

a whole bunch of cases for each possible characters with if statements to pick out the 
different fuzzy codings and adding letters to primary and secondary as they are identified.

```
.....

if (primary->length > 4)
SetAt(primary, 4, '\0');

if (secondary->length > 4)
SetAt(secondary, 4, '\0');

*codes = primary->str;
*++codes = secondary->str;

DestroyMetaString(original);
DestroyMetaString(primary);
DestroyMetaString(secondary);
}
```

Finally here is the snippet of my code that calls this method. I import the    double_metaphone.h and then in a method do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Filtered Word";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
    Word *word = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    char *codes;
    NSString *wordForMetaphone = [NSString stringWithString:word.spelling];
    DoubleMetaphone([wordForMetaphone UTF8String], &codes);
    NSLog(@"doubleMetaphone code = %s", codes);

    cell.textLabel.text = word.spelling;

return cell;
}
```

The log messages seems to execute with no issue, but the `cell.textLable.text = word.spelling` triggers the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. When I step through the code I can't po word.spelling either - I'm thinking that the C++ code is blowing up my pointers/memory. But I really don't know where to start to fix it.

Notes: Initially I just passed in `[word.spelling UTF*String]` but that encountered the same memory issue.
`word.spelling == @"a"` the first time through the code.
When I comment out my 4 lines of code the app runs fine.

I'm also not confident I'm setting up char *codes and referencing it correctly so I'm thinking that might be contributing to the issue - shouldn't that be an array of primary and secondary?

I did change the definition of the DoubleMetaphone method from

```
 DoubleMetaphone(char *str, char **codes)
```

because of a "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' " warning see [C++ deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char?lq=1). There are a couple of other methods in the C++ class that I also had to switch to const char* I'm hoping that isn't part of the problem?

Please help!

Comment: What is "word"?  Where did you get "cell"?

Comment: Word is an object from my model - to test the double_metaphone implementation I took my table of words (its a dictionary app) and thought to log the metaphone code for each one as the cell is drawn. The code snippet is from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: it gets the right 'word' with its spelling from the fetchedResultsController associated with the table.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, word.spelling was just a way to get a string to send to double_metaphone.... I'll try some hard coded strings to see if they behave differently.

Comment: So I just tested char *codes;
        NSString *wordForMetaphone = @"A";
        DoubleMetaphone([wordForMetaphone UTF8String], &codes); and as soon as the code moves on - trying to access the pre-existing object 'word' I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: So what is "word", how is it defined, and how do you create it?

Comment: `*++codes = secondary->str;` is a definite no-no; you're only passing the address of a pointer, not the first element of an array, so it's invalid.

Comment: to Hot Licks => I have a core data model for my dictionary that I set up when the app installs. I've included more of my code, I'm hoping that helps.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh dear, that line is part of the C++ or C implementation that I found on the web.... As it seems there is only primary and secondary I'll try to extending the C method to pass two variable into it rather than one... other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Awesome - I just did as you suggested creating two strings to pass in to extract the results and now it is working :-) Thumbs up to @molbdnilo....

Comment: @molbdnilo create me an answer so I can accept it :-) that was the problem line of code, even though I worked around it rather than figure out how to get the object C side to see the first member of an array as a char *.... you could educate me on what the C method would have liked for codes, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

```
    *++codes = secondary->str;
```

You're passing a pointer to *one* `char*` to the function, so `++codes` is an invalid pointer (you're probably overwriting something crucial that happens to be stored next to `codes` in the calling function).

If you want to return two things, you can either pass two `char**` parameters - one for "primary" and one for "secondary" - *or* you can pass a pointer to an array, like this:

```
char* outputs[2] = {0, 0};
DoubleMetaphone([wordForMetaphone UTF8String], outputs);
NSLog(@"doubleMetaphone primary = %s, secondary = %s", outputs[0], outputs[1]);

...
// In DoubleMetaphone:
codes[0] = primary->str;
codes[1] = secondary->str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use my standard C++11 version: [double_metaphone](https://github.com/pixelglow/double_metaphone). This should `#include` straight into an `.mm` (Objective-C++) file without any changes, and you can either convert from `std::string` to `NSString` or compose the `NSString` yourself using the callback version.