# Interact with Cocos2d-x Scene at android / ios native window

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I'd like to know if Its possible to interact with Cocos2d-x Scene?

Like if I press the button, I can call a method inside Cocos2d-x, for example to start an animation.

If yes, please provide me a sample.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. 
So on iOS: it's very simple, you just need to import the C++ header file in your objective c(mm file) and call. You might need to save the instance somewhere. This still applies to cocos2d-x - [Calling C++ method from Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456239/calling-c-method-from-objective-c)

Android: You need to define JNI function on C++ side and call from java.
Please refer this link : http://stnguyen.com/cocos2d-x/call-cpp-functions-from-java.html

Comment: yes, its possible. But its not really easy, you need to create a bridge to Objective-C++ then another to swift.

Answer (score 0):

For exchanging information between native layer and cocos2d-x versions 3.x and higher you can use this project:

https://github.com/alfonsocejudo/EasyNDK-for-cocos2dx3

It works well for Android, iOS and OSX.